# Forever logs keep growing

Tags: node.js, azure, logging, npm, forever

I run the NPM global module [Forever](https://www.npmjs.com/package/forever) on my Node server (on Azure). Always works fine to keep all my projects running.

There is 1 project on my server that perhaps has an issue or something that causes Forever to keep outputting to the log. There are 2 Forever logs that grow rapidly and to huge sizes:

```
9.7Gb  /home/azureuser/.forever/P_lf.log
1.3Gb  /home/azureuser/.forever/IEJR.log
```

Whilst I probably need to find out what's wrong with my project and fix it, I also need to fix this logging problem. My research shows I may need to do something with logrotate to stop this much disk space being used.

Any ideas?

Comment: You need to edit code and fix loging parts. not to log everything, only log necessary things, errors and etc. and if error so fix it. if it's expressjs there must be production mode to disable logging.

Comment: @num8er in the meantime, to clear space, is it safe to completely delete those 2 log files?

Comment: You can do like this:  "> /home/azureuser/.forever/P_lf.log"  (without quotes), it will truncate file contents

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are 2 moments:

1. You can edit Your app to log only necessary things and errors (can catch errors to prevent them), so Your logs will be smaller.
2. You can set cron job to cleanup log files every night (let's say every 03:00 AM):

   **0 3 * * * truncate -s 0 /home/azureuser/.forever/*.log**

   or odd days (to be able to keep logs one day for debug purposes):

   **0 3 * * 1,3,5 truncate -s 0 /home/azureuser/.forever/*.log**

Comment: Shouldn't logrotate be able to manage log sizes & truncation etc?

Comment: I've not used logrotate, but it's also can be solution. Being nodejs dev I try not to generate huge logs. So my server is clean. :)

Comment: read this if You think about logrotate: https://nrtechbytes.wordpress.com/2015/01/23/log-rotate-forever-log-files-nodejs/  but I don't love complicated configurations or keep additional daemon to control log. (:

Comment: if these logs are necessary to You so use https://logentries.com/ or something like this

Comment: In 2022 you need to this command: `forever cleanlogs` And of course you can add this to crontab.

Comment: @kodmanyagha to be honest after 6 years from my answer I would prefer to use log rotation. Also I would add that logs to be parsed by fluentd and etc. So there are so many ways to deal with logs… (:

Comment: Actually you're right. `forever cleanlogs` command cleans only inactive log files. It doesn't touch to active log files. log rotation is better.